# NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[GoogleChartComponent -> DataTableService

Tags: angular, typescript

Am trying to add google charts on Angular 8, but for some weird reason my page does not render and google chrome console throws an error

> ERROR NullInjectorError:
> StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[GoogleChartComponent ->
> DataTableService]:
> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[GoogleChartComponent -> DataTableService]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for DataTableService!

whenever I add the `DataTableService` to the providers under my Module I get another error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> 'angular-google-charts/lib/services/data-table.service'

This is my simple implementation
component.ts file

```
export class LabdashboardComponent implements AfterViewInit {
   title = 'Population (in millions)';
  type = ChartType.ColumnChart;
  data = [
    ["2012", 900, 390],
    ["2013", 1000, 400],
    ["2014", 1170, 440],
    ["2015", 1250, 480],
    ["2016", 1530, 540]
  ];
  columnNames = ['Year', 'Asia','Europe'];
  options = {};
  width = 550;
  height = 400;
  constructor(private service: ReportService) {
    this.subtitle = 'Lab Dashboard';
  }
```

component.html file

```
<google-chart #chart
                                      [title]="title"
                                      [type]="type"
                                      [data]="data"
                                      [columns]="columnNames"
                                      [options]="options"
                                      [width]="width"
                                      [height]="height">
                        </google-chart>
```

module.ts file

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(LabdashboardRoutes), NgbModule, GoogleChartsModule],
    declarations: [LabdashboardComponent, DateAgoPipe],
  providers:[ScriptLoaderService, LabdashboardComponent, DataTableService ]
})
export class LabdashboardModule { }
```

Tried the same on angular 12, works fine, but my project is on angular 8, and upgrading it is a rabbit hole. What am I missing? Am implementing using the current version of `angular-google-charts`

Comment: where do you import the "DataTableService" from? you may add it into the code with providers demonstration. `import { DataTableService} from "<Im interested in this path>"`

Comment: Have you deleted the node_modules and package-lock.json files and cleared the npm cache data and tried the command `npm i angular-google-charts --save`

Comment: If it works in Angular 12 but not in Angular 8, try using an older version like 1.1.6.

Comment: Hi @IAfanasov  `import {DataTableService} from "angular-google-charts/lib/services/data-table.service";`

Comment: Older version works, thank you @AliF50